# Lvalues and Rvalues in C

Tags: c

can anyone give me a proper explanation about lvalues and rvalues in c. I havent found a proper one. if anyone has a link can u please paste t as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

**l-values** are entities whose address (*usually exceptions: register variables*)can be taken & they reside in memory long enough to be referred to by an name.
**r-values** are <strike>variables</strike> objects whose address cannot be taken & they do not reside in memory long enough to be referred to by an name, they are nameless. Often also called as nameless temporary objects.

**[Sample Program:](http://ideone.com/OsBUK)**

```
int returnanInteger()
{
    int i = 10;
    return i;
}

void doSomething(int i)
{
    //do something, right now we don't care
}
int main()
{
   int i = 20;
   doSomething(returnanInteger());

   return 0;
}
```

In above program `i` in `main()` is an **l-value** because its address can be taken and it can be referred by an name.
While, in the statement:

```
doSomething(returnanInteger());
```

The value returned by `returnanInteger()` is an **r-value**, it's address cannot be taken and it does not remain in memory long enough to be referred by nay name.It is immediately copied to be passed as an argument to the function `doSomething()`.

Comment: your statement about l-values is quite missleading: compound literals and `malloc` provide lvalues, too. And not all lvalues allow to take the address of the underlying object, namely `register` variables don't. Your statement about rvalues is not much better: variable in C has a very specific meaning as a named object. You probably mean object.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The intent was to keep it as simple as possible for someone totally ignorant about them.If I had to provide the most accurate definition I would have just cited some C99 standard quotes but I doubt it would help the OP in understanding anything anyways. This gets the OP started with least basic idea.

Comment: it may be simple, but the effect is that it is just plain wrong.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I toned it down a bit to make the answer *pedantically accurate*, hope that satisfy's the point of contention.

Comment: thanks for the classification as "pedantic". I still don't think that your description is helpful enough to make the difference clear. You just don't stress the real difference between the two, namely between explicitly allocated objects and intermediates. E.g compound literals are also temporary objects, but which are lvalues.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I am afraid I don't know how to be more explicit without losing simplicity, and simplicity is the prime motive of my answer, maintaining accuracy with it is a difficult preposition, i tried to do so(*maybe not enough*) but I do not wish to make it more accurate at expense of losing the simplicity.I will leave that to be done by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the values on the right side of = ("equal" to sign in c programming) are rvalues.Like 
x = 23;
c = 'x';
int *ptr = &x;

here 23 , 'x' and '&x" are the rvalues
Correspondingly x , c and *ptr are the lvalues.They represent the variables or objects in the memory
You can never put the rvalues on the left side of = ("equal" to sign in c programming)

See this link - http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5696  for more info.
rgds
Softy

Answer (score 0):

A simplification would be to see lvalues as typed "objects" that have an explicit allocation in the program, either as variables, compound literals or through `malloc` or similar mechanisms. Depending on their type, lvalues can be modifiable or not (specified with `const` for the type), and you may be allowed to take the address of it or not (specified with `register` for the declaration of variables).

An rvalue is just a "value" that the program produces as an intermediate step in an evaluation, and for which the compiler may freely choose the particular representation that suits best. Rvalues may not be modified and their address can usually not be taken. (There are very special circumstance that allow to take it for array component evaluation.)

Answer (score 0):

**lvalues (left-values)** are (usually) found on the left side of the equality "=" operator.

**rvalues (right-values)** are found on the right side of the equality "=" operator.

**lvalues** are objects located in a memory location (address). lvalues get deleted once the block in which they were declared gets terminated.

**rvalues** are temporary values that get deleted as soon as they are initialized or assigned to an lvalue.

Ex:`int a = 1 + 2;`

In the example above, "a" is the lvalue since it is in the left side of the equality operator and the expression "1 + 2" is the rvalue since it is in the right side of the equality operator. Once this statement is executed, the variable "a" (now initialized to 3) persists in memory, while the expression "1 + 2" gets automatically deleted.

Here is a link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx