# C operator classification in terms of lvalue and rvalue requirement

Tags: c

Reference to "rvalue" in C11 standard is limited to following footnote.

> "What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard
>   described as the ‘‘value of an expression’’"

where as ken Thompson's [B manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/kbman.html) uses the terms lvalue & rvalue heavily. please note the &,++ operators below ( excerpt from B manual)

```html
rvalue ::=
    ( rvalue )
    lvalue
    constant
    lvalue assign rvalue
    inc-dec lvalue
    lvalue inc-dec
    unary rvalue
    & lvalue
    rvalue binary rvalue
    rvalue ? rvalue : rvalue
    rvalue ( {rvalue {, rvalue}0 }01 )
```

```html
lvalue ::=
    name
    * rvalue
    rvalue [ rvalue ]
```

similarly C++ seems to have a description of lvalue to rvalue conversions ([lvalue_to_rvalue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850536/lvalue-to-rvalue-implicit-conversion))  and [lvalue_to_rvalue2](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c)

I have few questions regarding the above statements.

1. is there such a "reference"(links etc) exist for operators in C "similar" to B manual requirement of operators in lvalue & rvalue terms? ( please see that I am familiar with lvalue requirements of certain C operators)
2. the term "rvalue" is widely used in B and used in C++, why is this missing in C?
3. is lvalue to rvalue conversions are specific to C++ and not for C (covered indirectly by the standard), if covered will you please quote the relevant sections from standard?

Comment: The C11 description of an rvalue as the result of an express seems quite straightforward.  C++ compilers do a lot more conversions and translations so the rules are complex since constructors and destructors and a lot of other plumbing is involved.  See [lvalue and rvalue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038414/lvalue-and-rvalue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lvalues and Rvalues in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646823/lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c)

Comment: @mpromonet - The question you referred is more to do with what are lvalues and rvalues. current question is more about whether there is a comprehensive list available as similar to the one pasted from B language,why their is separation in definition between C/C++ , and why C departed from the notion used in B and in C++

Answer (score 2):

The difference between C and C++ regarding to rvalues is probably the function overloading and references.

In C, however, rules are pretty simple: the left operand several operators must be lvalues. Any other other operand can be an l-value or an rvalue. A quick search through the C99 standard gives as requirements for lvalues:

- prefix increment and decrement operator
- postfix increment and decrement operator
- unary `&` operator
- left of any assignment operator

So there is no necessity to put a name to the value of an expression (rvalue). They are just expressions, and their value is used.

About when an lvalue is produced:

- an identifier (a variable)
- a string literal
- a lvalue in parentheses
- the result of the access-to-member `.` operator, if the left operand is an lvalue
- the result of the pointer-to-member `->` operator
- a compound literal (for example `(int[]{1,2}`)
- the result of the unary `*` operator
- the result of the index operator `[]`

Notably, these are **not** lvalues (some of them are/may be lvalues in C++, left as an exercise to the reader):

- the result of a cast
- the result of the conditional ternary operator `?:`
- the result of the assignment operator `=`
- the result of the comma operator `,`

Why is used in C references, even if there is not in the C standard? Well, it is much easier to say *rvalue* than to say *value of an expression*. And the term is familiar enough not to create any confusion.

Comment: but the requirement of lvalue for certan operators also creates the necessity to know which operations creates lvalue and rvalue. for eg a cast operator or & operator doesn't produce lvalue making &i++ or (int)i++ invalid. if we look at the B grammar above it is clear which one is an lvalue. please see the confusion created  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446489/casting-a-pointer-does-not-produce-an-lvalue-why

Comment: @bare_metal: You are right, and those are covered in the standard too. But I think that you didn't ask for these details, did you? Anyway, I can summarize them if you wish.

Comment: that would be nice, but when you summarize eventually wont it look something similar to the grammar shown in B? (to say +a, a+1 is an rvalue, you might need to say unary operator except certain operators, then binary and so on ). it would be great if you can point out if such a link is existing or if a similar list can be compiled.

Comment: @bare_metal: The difference between rvalues and lvalues is not in the grammar, but in the comments. I'll add that in a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer to this hoping that it might help someone who is looking for the same thing.
I found the operator classification table based on lvalue/rvalue in Kenneth A.Reek's Book "Pointers On C". section 5.4.3 of this book has an operator precedence table with the lexp/rexp requirement of each operator ( whether the operands of the operator is lexp/rexp and whether the result is an lexp/rexp).please note that this is based on C89.